# jQuery won't find custom tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML with several custom tags. I want to find all but two ('start', 'end') and unwrap them. jQuery.find() seems to only find these custom tags when I search what's in the document, not when I search a jQuery object. What am I doing wrong?

Should be self-explanatory in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hpNN3/2/

Here's the javascript part:

```
var raw = $('pre').html();
var html = $(raw);
var starts = html.find('start');
var spans = html.find('span');

//this returns nothing
console.log(starts)
// works - can find in object
console.log(spans)
//this works
console.log($('start'));


//only picks up spans, not annotations
// I want this to return the innerHTML of the pre, stripping all tags except for 'start' and 'end' -- but retain the contents of those tags.
var cleaned = html.find(':not(start, end)').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});

console.log(cleaned);

$('#clean').html(cleaned)
```

and an example of the HTML:

```
<span class="ng-scope">CTAGCTCTCTGGAGATTAACGAGGAGAAATACTAGAtTGGTTCAT</span>
<start feat="1" class="ng-scope"></start>
<annotation index="1" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(238, 153, 238); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
    <span tooltip="Another Promoter" tooltip-placement="mouse" tooltip-append-to-body="true" ng-transclude="" class="ng-scope">
        <span class="ng-scope">GATCATAAgcttgaat</span>
    </span>
</annotation>
<end feat="1" class="ng-scope"></end>
<span class="ng-scope">tagccaaacttatt</span>
```

which should be:

`CTAGCTCTCTGGAGATTAACGAGGAGAAATACTAGAtTGGTTCAT<start feat="1" class="ng-scope"></start>GATCATAAgcttgaat<end feat="1" class="ng-scope"></end>tagccaaacttatt`

Thanks

Comment: html with custom tags is no longer html

Comment: with the exception of <IE6 you can create your own custom tags and browser will recognize them. regardless, they don't mess up the DOM and are interpreted correctly at least in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and that's not what I was asking. If jQuery is known not to pick up custom elements, then that would be a helpful answer. But as shown in the fiddle, it can pick up custom tags, at least when in the document, not necessary when in an object.

Comment: Why write HTML in this manner? What benefits does tag `<start></start>` have over `<div class="start"></div>` or `<span class="start"></span>`? Not to mention, it is faster to use selector `$('.className')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies with the your initial variables:

```
var raw = $('pre').html();
var html = $(raw);
```

This translates to `var html = $($('pre').html())`, which will not match any element.  The reason being that, since the selector is not preceded by an `#` or `.`, it is looking ***literally*** looking for the tag:

```
<start feat="11" class="ng-scope">
</start>
<annotation index="11" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(238, 204, 153); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
</annotaion>
```

etc...

Here is a demo of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpNN3/7/

---

Simply do the following:

```
var html = $('pre');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpNN3/6/

Comment: ok - but this only unwraps them if they're in the DOM. I don't want to manipulate the DOM directly - I want to make an object (not tied to the document) and do my transformation there.